# how to get model with backbone if i have it's URI?

Tags: backbone.js, tastypie

I'm using django+tastypie+backbone.js with backbone-relational.
Let's say i have model(coffee script):

```
class Track extends Backbone.RelationalModel
```

And somehow i get the first object's URI:

```
api/track/1
```

Result in JSON have to be something like:

```
{
   'title': 'Mytrack',
   'length': '120'
}
```

How can i get full model JSON with all attributes using this URI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the model's `urlRoot` (/api/track), then create a new model with the id you want (1), and call `.fetch` on the model. The fetch call will be asynchronous, so you need to wait for the success callback before you can access the full properties:

```
class Track extends Backbone.RelationalModel
  urlRoot:"/api/track"

track = new Track id:1
track.fetch 
  success:(model) -> console.log model
```